# MySQL Enable the server to communicate via TCP/IP

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a problem with MySQL,

I would like to allow the access to my databases from other machines. I edited `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in the "mysqld.cnf" file. Then I typed `netstat -tln` in my shell and I got this :

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Therefore, I don't understand why it doesn't work. Indeed, currently, I can just connect on localhost.

I hope someone will help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: I'm new to MySQL and VPS administration. What should I do to fix this ?

Comment: OVH is my provider.

Comment: It's sunday so their support is closed. I have hoped someone could help me here ^^.

Comment: http://docs.ovh.ca/en/guides-network-firewall.html

Comment: It's probably a `firewalld` or `iptables` issue relating to network access. Which solution to use depends on what OS and distribution you're using.

Comment: I'm using Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: That's good because [`ufw` is actually really pleasant to use](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) compared to other solutions. Some more examples [from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands). I'd strongly recommend being restrictive about which IPs you open up MySQL to. You don't want to be open to random probes.

Comment: I tried with ufw but it still not working :( I added this with ufw : `3306 ALLOW 149.202.2.152`

Comment: Did you check if your user itself is allowed to connect from anything other than localhost? Check e.g. `select * from mysql.user;`.

Comment: I can't do this command from the shell. `select * from mysql.user;`

Comment: Saying "not working" isn't very descriptive. Does it connect and reject because of a password? Does it time out?

Comment: I don't know, I tried to connect a Minecraft plugin to the database and it said that the connection has failed. I tried to connect with the same plugin on a database hosted by a Minecraft server host... and it has worked. Therefore, I don't understand why I can't connect the Minecraft plugin to my own database. What's wrong ? I don't think there is any problem with the password because I can connect with this couple user-password on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @titi157 you should verify if your user has the right to access remotely. default is: he can only log in from localhost. This would explain your problems. If you can't use `select * from mysql.user;`: do you have a root password? Use this and retry. Or check your admin console of your host, you have to have the ability to manage your users, and, in this case, the host-part of your users, somewhere.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks a lot for your advice, I finally found the problem :). Here is a tutorial to grant the remote access : https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in the database names "mysql" there is a "user" table but every hosts of this table are localhost so you need to grant privilege for the specific IP that need to connect to your database. By doing this, you will enables the remote access for the specific IP address.

Here is a tutorial to grant the remote access : [easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access](http://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access)